# What are the benefits of running Kerberos with an authorization-backing server like LDAP/Active Directory/SPNEGO?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, kerberos

I've been tasked with implementing a Single Sign-On solution in an environment which uses Kerberos with an Active Directory server for the actual storing of the users and their groups. I understand that Kerberos does not support privileges/groups and that this is the reason to be forced to use a backing server like, for example, LDAP, or Active Directory. This is all fine and clear, but what I don't quite understand is ***why*** you would still be using Kerberos, when you could simply be connecting to LDAP or Active Directory directly instead and dropping the whole overhead of yet another server.

What am I missing here...? Please advise! Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Their is no overhead for another server. Active Directory combines all necessary services in one product.

Kerberos has tremendous benenfits:

- One login for all systems
- Transparent subsequent login
- Ciphered ticket exchange, even full transport encryption is possible
- Delegation of credential is supported out of the box
- Implemented and well documented in Unix and Windows for almost two decades

I use Kerberos via AD for years in Java and C on Unix and Windows with great success. I wouldn't use anything else in a corporate environment.